# Calling a function of a template class, in a template function?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to call a member function of a template class inside of a member function as follows:

Caller:

```
i->scene->AddComponent<MeshRenderEntityData>(child);
```

Template function (in header):

```
template<class cTy>
void AddComponent(DEntity e)
{
    DComponentStorage<cTy>* cs = this->template GetComponentStorage<cTy>();
    cs->RegisterEntity(e);
}
```

This is causing a linker error. Without the line `cs->RegisterEntity(e);` it compiles just fine. I want it to call the function of the template class from within the template function. The call to AddComponent() is from an exe, but the class containing that function is in a dll. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

The error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl dengine::DComponentStorage::RegisterEntity(unsigned __int64)" (_*imp*?RegisterEntity@?$DComponentStorage@VMeshRenderEntityData@dengine@@@dengine@@QEAAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl dengine::DScene::AddComponent(unsigned __int64)" (??$AddComponent@VMeshRenderEntityData@dengine@@@DScene@dengine@@QEAAX_K@Z) dtest   R:\dengine\dtest\dtest.obj  1

Comment: What exact error does it cause?

Comment: Unresolved external symbol. Forgot to add it to the question.

Comment: Where do you define `void DComponentStorage::RegisterEntity`?

Comment: In a file called DScene.h. Its a normal member function inside the class.

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Comment: Does your DLL export the member function?

Comment: Your question did not point us to the problem :-(. Potential problems: Template defined in header and not instantiated anywhere/invisible for all translation units. Template hidden in a namespace. Header included with `extern "C"` or something like that. Generated object file with template instance not linked.